# Upgraded Appcelerator now ios Simulators will not work

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, appcelerator

I have upgraded Appcelerator and xCode after a decent hiatus from doing development in it. I have created a brand new project and attempted to run it in the ios simulator only to be greeted with the following error:

> [ERROR] :  Invalid "--ios-version" value "12.1" Accepted values:
>      12.2

For help, run: `titanium.js` help build

I have been searching for a while on this and no one seems to have presented a decent answer on how to fix this. If anyone could provide any insight it would be greatly appreciated.

Titanium SDK is 8.0.1.GA if that helps at all.

Comment: did you try to change target version of iOS project?

Comment: The only targets available are 12.1 targets. I'm sure this is a silly configuration issue, but I've dumped a ton of hours down it.